# Window Count and Probability based on range

Tags: excel, pandas, series

I have a value column in my dataframe. I want to categorize the value as per following:

range1=(Values ranging from 400-500)

range2=(Values ranging from 200-300)

range3=(Values ranging from 100-200)

I need to compute the incremental count of the values corresponding to each range i.e range count and their corresponding probabilities. To elaborate more, I have listed an example below.

The Column Count_range and Prob is what I want to compute

[image]

> Note: In the prob. column, for the 5th row, the value= 255 corresponds to range2 and the number of occurrences till seen now for that corresponding range is 1 and total number of rows seen till now is 5.
> so, prob=1/5=0.2.
> Similarly, in the next row, we see the value corresponding to same range, so we increment its range count to 2 and hence now, prob= 2/6=0.33

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your sample occupies the range A1:C12 in a worksheet you might use the formulas below in B2 and C2. Both formulas can be copied down to the end of the sheet.

```
[B2] =MATCH(A2,{1000,500,400,300},-1)-1
[C2] =COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)/COUNT(B$2:B2)
```

The MATCH function will return an error if a value greater than 1000 is evaluated. It will return count-range #3 for any value 300 or lower. If you need 300 to be included in count-range #2 change the array in the formula to something like {1000,499,399,299}. Decimals may also be used, like {1000,499.9,399.9,299.9}.

The COUNTIF ranges like B$2:B2 expand as you copy them down, from B$2, which is absolute and will not change, to B3, B4, B5 etc. thereby creating a range from the top of the column at B2 to the current row, ignoring everything that might be below the row in which the formula resides.

Answer (score 0):

```
def state(x):
 if x >=100 and x<=200:
    return "Range3"
 if x >=200 and x<=300:
    return "Range2"
 if x >=400 and x<=500:
    return "Range1"

 df['state'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: state(x))
 df['Count_range'] = df.groupby('state').cumcount()+1
 df['Prob'] =df['Count_range']/(df.index+1)
```

Define the category for the ranges using state function on Values column and perform a cumulative count after grouping them by state using pandas.groupby. Finally, to get the prob column, divide the Count_range column values by corresponding index to get the Averages respectively.

[image]